# How do I make a hierarchy of messages data?

Tags: php, mysql, hierarchical-data

I have to make a parent-child hierarchy of messages.I have two sets of messages, one that I download and save into table from twitter.These are going to be root level messages. Second set of messages are those which user(will) enter as child nodes of any of these root level messages. I am displaying root level messages as an unordered list in my application like:

```
  - root_msg1
  - root_msg2
  - root_msg3
```

This much I have done.
Next step that I need to do is add child nodes to these root level messages. Like user could click on any of these root level messages in the unordered list OR point out somehow which root node's child she wants to enter and enter a message that should appear as a child message of that root level message. Like

```
  - root_msg1 (user clicks on this root msg & enter a msg that appears as its child)
     - msg1_child1
     - msg1_child2
  - root_msg2
  - root_msg3 (user enter a child msg of this root level msg same way)
     - msg3_child1
```

1stly I would need help how I store this hierarchy into database. Then depending on that, how could I add a new child node into database so that it could be displayed as a child of a specific root.

**EDIT**

I have had the hierarchy for the root messages that I save into table exactly same as Birth put under with exception that I do get any parent_id from twitter, just msg_id.(Actually that is basic reason for storing tweets into database to add value into parent_id column!). But what basic problem I encounter is 'how do I know which node is a child of which parent', **As I stated in OP that all root messages are displayed as an unordered list on HTML FORM and user will select from those list items under which one she wants to enter a child node by clicking on it.The root message(i.e. list item clicked) has a msg_id that is stored into table & that is going to be parent id for child node, but I need to get that when user clicks on root & how do I get it.This is my basic problem that stuck me.** Once I get it, then hopefully its as simple as inserting a new record into db. 
This is my schema:

```
|---------+-----------+-------------|
| msg_id  | parent_id |    msg      |
|---------+-----------+-------------|
|       1 | NULL      |   msg1      |
|       2 | NULL      |   msg2      |
|       3 | NULL      |   msg3      |
|         | ?         | msg1_child1 |
|         | ?         | msg1_child2 |
|         | ?         | msg3_child1 |
|---------+-----------+-------------|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing hierarchical data in a database is a bit of a complex topic, and it mostly depends how exactly you need to use the data. Generally though, a very simple way to do it is to just give every row a "parent id" that can point to records in the same table. If a node is a root node, this column would be `NULL` or `0`.

So then, for your example data, you'd have a table something like this:

```
|---------+-----------+-------------|
| node_id | parent_id | title       |
|---------+-----------+-------------|
|       1 | NULL      | root_msg1   |
|       2 | NULL      | root_msg2   |
|       3 | NULL      | root_msg3   |
|       4 | 1         | msg1_child1 |
|       5 | 1         | msg1_child2 |
|       6 | 3         | msg3_child1 |
|---------+-----------+-------------|
```

You can find all the root nodes by selecting ones with `NULL` in the `parent_id` column, and you can find child nodes of each other node by searching on the parent's id.

Comment: @Chad Birch, I have had my all root message with exactly same schema in table as you made here. But what basic problem I encounter is 'how do I know which node is a child of which parent', As I stated in OP that user will select from the HTML FORM the root message to which she wants to enter a child node either by clicking on it or any other way that I don't know. This is my basic problem that stuck me.

Comment: @XCeptable: I don't know what you mean. The value in the `parent_id` column tells you which one is the parent. Row #4 and #5 both have `1` in that column, meaning that their parent is row #1. Row #6 has `3`, so its parent is row #3.

Comment: @Chad Birch, But how did I get that value form an HTML form? OK, I just ask a question to make you understand I know its bit complicated,sorry for inconvenience.As I stated in OP that all root messages are displayed as unordered list on HTML FORM. Now user wants to add a child node to any message in the list, she clicks on that message. How do I get the msg_id of that root message on which user click so that I add that to parent id field of child message?

Comment: @XCeptable, if you're making each node into a link that they can click to add, then you'll have the ID in each link. So for example the first one would link to something like `add_message.php?parent=1` and the third one would link to `add_message.php?parent=3`. Then you use `$_GET['parent']` on the add_message.php page to see what value was passed (meaning which link was clicked).

Comment: @Chad Birch, that seems very cool. But can you give some suggestion about how do I use that value in my situation. Like I donot want user to move away from form where they click on a root. So there is a msg box under that list where users enter child msg, so when user send msg they enter there, this $_GET['parent'] is also send with that that I receive on another script. I hope you would have understood my point.How could I achieve that.

Comment: @Chad Birch, one more actually basic question is how to add msg_id to 'add_message.php?parent=1'? i.e 1 here. As this value is stored in table.

Comment: I can't really explain those things here, they're pretty basic parts of web development, since you need to know how to do things like that to pass information around your application. I'd suggest looking for some basic tutorials that show how to do web dev with the languages/libraries you're using.

Comment: @Chad Birch, actually I know how to use add_message.php?parent=3 as link to pass values in php. I was not sure about how to get value from table & add it here. Hopefully will get done when will do it in morning.thanX many many times Chad Birch for your lots of help.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand this correctly you're wondering about the html right?
well you just create another unorderded list after the li it's assign to.

for the mysql part you could use Joins to put it inside a single query.
to be more specific what i meant was you keep the child messages in a diffrent
table and the parents in a separate one, and join them through a common denominator
that could be set through GET/POST/SESSION or whatever you find fit to use.

Regards

Comment: actually this is my basic problem how do I relate a child with a corresponding parent to which user wants it to be a child. I do not know how could I get an input or something to be used for taht association when user click on any root msg in the list. According to yours suggestion, I have already have all root messages in a table. Now when I get child in another, how do I know which msg is child of which root??

Comment: does twitter give you the id of the parent for a message?

Comment: @Dan D, I have table exactly same as this with parent_id null for root. Twitter has no hierarchical structure that's why I am downloading tweet to table to manipulate those.This is basic problem I encounter 'how do I know which node is a child of which parent', As I stated in OP that user will select from the HTML FORM the root message to which she wants to enter a child node either by clicking on it or any other way that I don't know. This is my basic problem that stuck me

Comment: @Dan D, no, each message has its own id. Twitter has no hierarchy.That's why I am saving tweets to manipulate those. One thing here should be important that I will store child nodes on local db in same table direct from my app. Those will not send back to twitter as this is only way as I see to store tweets with parent id. But for that I need to get the id of message(that is in stored in table) on which user clicks.